# Select <divs> within parent <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent `<div>`, `#amwcontentwrapper`, which has a series of `divs` within it with their own classes and ids.

I want to use jQuery to select these child `divs`, and IF they have the class `.amwhidden`, do nothing, but if not, remove the `.amwshown` class and add the `.amwhidden` class.

This is what I have so far, but it is not working. I think it may be my selecting of the child `divs` within the parent.

Can anybody see any obvious problems? Thanks for your help.

```
  if ($('#amwcontentwrapper > div').hasClass('amwhidden')){

    } else {
    $('#amwcontentwrapper > div').fadeIn(600, function(){
    $('#amwcontentwrapper > div').removeClass('amwshown');
    $('#amwcontentwrapper > div').addClass('amwhidden');  
    });
    }
```

And here is the basic html that I am using:

```
<div class="amwshown" id="amwintro">
Intro Section, which should have the 'amwshown' class removed, and the 
'amwhidden' class added, when the jQuery runs. Currently, this does not happen.
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** Using War10ck's solution in the comments below (i.e. `$('#amwcontentwrapper > div.amwshown')`) I have managed to get the classes changing as I wished. However, those which have had the .amwshown class removed and .amwhidden class added still show on the page, despite the CSS looking like this:

```
.amwhidden {
display:none;
}

.amwshown {
display:block;
}
```

Looking at the Dev Tools, it seems that, when the jQuery is run (on a click event) the classes are changing, but any classes which are having the `.amwshown` class added (thus displaying them on the page) are also having the a `<style>` tag added to them which makes them `display:block;`

When I then press another button, which should hide the aformentioned `<div>` to make way for another one, the class is being changed to `.amwhidden`, but that `<style>` tag is not being deleted, so even though it has the `.amwhidden` class, it is still  on the page.

I've created a JSFiddle here, if anybody still wants to help!

`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#buybutton').click(function() {

    $('#amwcontentwrapper > div.amwshown').fadeIn(600, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('amwshown').addClass('amwhidden');
    });

    if ($('#amwbuy').hasClass('amwshown')) {} else {
      $('#amwbuy').fadeIn(600, function() {
        $('#amwbuy').removeClass('amwhidden');
        $('#amwbuy').addClass('amwshown');
      });
    }
  });






  $('#phdbutton').click(function() {

    $('#amwcontentwrapper > div.amwshown').fadeIn(600, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('amwshown').addClass('amwhidden');
    });

    if ($('#amwphd').hasClass('amwshown')) {} else {
      $('#amwphd').fadeIn(600, function() {
        $('#amwphd').removeClass('amwhidden');
        $('#amwphd').addClass('amwshown');
      });
    }
  });



});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #000000;
  width: 10%;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
#amwcontentwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 5%;
}
.amwshown {
  display: block;
}
.amwhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="amwsidebar">
  <span class="sidebarbutton" id="phdbutton">PhD Button</span>
  <br />
  <br />
  <span class="sidebarbutton" id="buybutton">Buy Button</span> 
</div>



<div id="amwcontentwrapper">

  <div class="amwshown" id="amwintro">
    <p>An intro section to welcome the visitor. Disappears when one of the other sections is clicked.</p>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>

  <div class="amwhidden" id="amwbuy">
    Buy Section
  </div>

  <div class="amwhidden" id="amwphd">
    PhD Section
  </div>

</div>
```

`

Comment: post ur html as well

Comment: `$('#amwcontentwrapper > div.amwshown').removeClass('amwshown').addClass('amwhidden');`...

Comment: `hasClass` isn't going to manage each instance for you

Comment: Have you tried the `.each()` function to loop through all the divs?

Comment: Thanks War10ck; your solution seems to change the classes as I wish. However, I am still not getting the desired effect for a different reason; I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all help, it has prompted some brainstorming which has solved this issue.

Instead of adding the `.amwhidden` class and removing the .`amwhidden` class using jQuery, I have just created a `.amwsection` class, which all the sections belong to which has an initial `display` value of `none`. So far, so good; all of the sections are not there when you load up the page.

Then I use the `.css` jQuery function to change the `display:none` to `display:block` when the corresponding button is clicked, and changing all other `.amwsections` to `display:none`. This works just fine, but the effect is quite abrupt; there is no fading in, as you would get if you used the `.animate` function. `.animate`, however, does not work with the `display` value.

`.fadeOut` and `.fadeIn` to the rescue! By wrapping the .css change in these, I can create a fading in/out effect and can still use the `display` value.

Here is one example of this code.

- The `#buybutton` is the button to be pressed.
- `#amwintro` is just something which appears when the page loads - it will now be set to display:none if this is the first button pressed.
- The `.amwsection` are **all of the hidden sections**. This portion of the code just resets all of them. This and the `#amwintro` section happen very quickly (1/100th of a second) to keep response time good.
- The `#amwbuy` is the **specific section** that I want to reveal. As you can see, this fades in over a longer period.

Currently only tested in Chrome, but I think I've got it!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#buybutton').click(function() {
    $('#amwintro').fadeOut(1, function() {  
   $(this).css({
    display:'none',
    });
    });
    $('.amwsection').fadeOut(1, function() {  
   $(this).css({
    display:'none',
    });
    });

 $('#amwbuy').fadeIn(600, function() {  
   $(this).css({
        display:'block',
    });
    });  

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not` to remove the elements you do not want, like this:

```
$('#amwcontentwrapper > div').not('.amwhidden')
    .removeClass('amwshown')
    .addClass('amwhidden');
```

And work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amwcontentwrapper").children().each(function(elem, x) {
    if ($(x).attr("class") == "amwhidden") {
      alert($(x).attr("class"));
      $(x).removeClass("amwhidden").addClass("amwshow");
      alert($(x).attr("class"));

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="amwcontentwrapper">
  <div class="amwhidden"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try each as follow,

```
   $("#amwcontentwrapper div").each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('amwhidden'))
            //DO something
        else
            //DO something 
    });
```